# Spark ALS model.transform(test) drops rows from test. What could be the reason?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, als

`test` (a table with columns:  `user_id`, `item_id`, `rating`, with **6.2M rows**)

```
als = ALS(userCol="user_id",
                itemCol="item_id",
                ratingCol="rating",
                coldStartStrategy="drop",
                implicitPrefs=True)
model = als.fit(train)
predictions = model.transform(test)
```

`predictions` (a table with columns: `user_id`, `item_id`, `rating`, `prediction`, but with only **1.7M rows**)

Why did `model.transform(test)` drop rest of the rows? It should have been able to calculate prediction score for all `user_id`, `item_id` combination, right?

Is it because I have used `coldStartStrategy="drop"`?

- But if there is a rating calculated for all `user_id`, `item_id` combinations in `test`, no row should be dropped, yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because I have used the `coldStartStrategy="drop"` option only. It's dropping rows corresponding to users and items which had no interactions corresponding to them in training data.